# Referencing variable inside template call - sightly

Tags: sightly, htl

I'm trying to call a variable inside quotes inside a data-sly-template call. I would expect the output to include my string with the appropriate varible inside quotes. Below is the template and the string I'm using to call it:

Template:

```
    <!-- template -->
    <template data-sly-template.bnrButton="${ @ style='String: button color class (default btn-primary)', classes='String: additional component button classes', text='String: button text (translation key)', defaultText='String: default button text (translation key)', link='String: link target for button (# is default)', fullWidth='Boolean: whether to display button in full width of container', noFollow='Boolean: if button should have a nofollow tag (no is def)', gaCategory='String: GA Category', gaEvent='String: GA Event', gaLabel='String: GA Label', gaAction='String: GA Action'}">
    <a class="btn ${style || 'btn-primary'} hidden-print ${classes}${fullWidth ? ' btn-full-width' : ''}" role="button" href="${link || '#'}" rel="${noFollow ? 'nofollow' : ''}" onclick="${gaEvent @ context = 'scriptString'}">${text || defaultText  @ i18n}</a>    
    </template> 

    <!-- call made to the template -->
    <sly data-sly-call="${patterns.bnrButton @ style='btn-secondary-light', classes='btn-sm', text=teaser.libraryButtonHeading, defaultText='View Library', link=teaser.myLibraryLink.href, fullWidth='true', newWindow='false', gaEvent='trackEvent(&#39;Test 1&#39;,&#39;Test 2&#39;,&#39;${teaser.teaserMessage}&#39;)'}"></sly>
```

If tried a number of combinations to get teaser.teaserMessage to print the authored message, but have been having issues because the patterns call is already inside quotes. I want to be able to pass a single string (called in the template call) to the template that includes all the information it needs for the onclick.

Thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-sly-test.variable_name` before the template call to store the value into a variable:

```
<sly data-sly-test.gaEvent="${'trackEvent(&#39;Test 1&#39;,&#39;Test 2&#39;,&#39;{0}&#39;)' @ format=teaser.teaserMessage}"
     data-sly-call="${patterns.bnrButton @ ..., gaEvent=gaEvent }"></sly>
```

Comment: where would you add that in the string above to pass it along to the template? Is the data-sly-test in the template or in the template call?

Comment: @Blaris before the template call